# What does "had an out" refer to?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Malcolm speaks about River:

> Malcolm: I could have left her there. I **had an out**. Hell, I had every
> reason in the 'verse to leave her lay and haul anchor.

What does "had an out" refer to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per Google Oxford Languages

"Out"

1. Noun
   INFORMAL
   a way of escaping from a problem or dilemma.
   "he was desperately looking for an out"

Comment: Suggested as 'American slang', circa 1900

Comment: Maybe yes to AME slang, but I would still consider it current.